# Android Database Problems

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am creating an application where I am calling my database from a different activity but I keep getting all sorts of errors from on the database side of things. At first, I was getting an

> "SQLiteException no such data"

and when I deleted my application and installed it back, it's now

> "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19:
>   constraint failed"

I have no idea what to do anymore. Have gone through so many different examples on creating database but I don't know if I am missing something?.. Here is my code for the database side:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class DBAdapter {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MemoData.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Memo";

    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String NAME = "Title";
    public static final String START_DATE = "start_date";
    public static final String END_DATE = "end_date";
    public static final String NOTES = "notes";

    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table Memo (_id integer primary key autoincrement,"   
        + "Title text not null, start_date text not null,"
        + "end_date text not null, "
        + "notes text not null);";

    private final Context context;   
    private DBHelper dbhelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        dbhelper = new DBHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DBHelper(Context context){
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }


        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG,"upgrading Database from version"+ oldVersion+ "to"
                    +newVersion+ "which oold data will be lost");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXITS Memo");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public DBAdapter open()throws SQLException {
        db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
        dbhelper.close();
    }

  public long createItem(String Title, String start_date,String end_date,String notes){
             open();
            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(NAME, Title);
            initialValues.put(START_DATE, start_date);
            initialValues.put(END_DATE, end_date);
            initialValues.put(NOTES, notes);

            return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
            }

      public Cursor retrieveItems(){
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
            String[] resultColumns = new String[] {NAME,START_DATE,END_DATE,NOTES };     
     Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, resultColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

            Integer cindex = cursor.getColumnIndex("Title");
            String result = "Result = ";

            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do {
                    result += cursor.getString(cindex)+ "-";
                }while(cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            return cursor;
        }
}
```

and here is the main error output:

```
08-23 22:38:17.104: ERROR/Database(775): Error inserting notes=Notes: end_date=Due Date: Title=Name of Item: start_date=Start Date:
08-23 22:38:17.104:ERROR/Database(775): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed

08-23 22:38:17.104: ERROR/Database(775):at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)

08-23 22:38:17.104: ERROR/Database(775):at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:66)

08-23 22:38:17.104: ERROR/Database(775):at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1313)

08-23 22:38:17.104: ERROR/Database(775):at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1173)

08-23 22:38:17.104: ERROR/Database(775):at com.Memo.DBAdapter.createItem(DBAdapter.java:94)

08-23 22:38:17.104: ERROR/Database(775):at com.Memo.NewItem.save(NewItem.java:365)
```

Comment: Please fix the double-spacing in this code block. This is unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onUpgrade event, you are dropping the table DATABASE_NAME, but shouldn't that be DATABASE_TABLE?

Nothing (besides that) jumps out at me, are you getting this error when you instantiate your DBAdapter object?  Is the error happening in the onCreate event or someplace else?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, i have corrected it. The error is coming from the createItem() method. its giving an "Error inserting" on the values.

Comment: sorry, i have cleaned up the code a bit and added the main error message. This is what i get and i have no idea why?.

Comment: Well the only constraint I can see is that everything is "not null".  Although the error message makes it look like everything has a value, I'd double check that.

Also, I've read that this can sometimes occur if there are some locks in place.  Looking at your code, it's not consistent with how it opens the database, sometimes using a local variable others using a member variable, and you'll want to make sure you are calling close() when you are done.  I don't think that is the problem, but there is some potential for it, depending on how your other classes are using it.